# How to install mysqlDb for MySQL and Python on Windows

Tags: python, mysql

I am a .NET developer trying to install `mysqldb` for python I keep having this error message

> raise improperlyconfigured("error loading mysqldb module: %s" % e)
>   django.core.exceptions.improperlyconfigured: error loading mysqldb
>   module: no module named mysqldb>

I am following this instruction from [this site](http://sourceforge.net/project/shownotes.php?release_id=303257)

I do not understand these lines

> windows .......
>
> c:...> python setup.py install   c:...> python setup.py
>   bdist_wininst
>
> the latter example should build a windows installer package, if you
>   have the correct tools. in any event, you *must* have a c compiler.
>   additionally, you have to set an environment variable (mysqlroot)
>   which is the path to your mysql installation. in theory, it would be
>   possible to get this information out of the registry, but like i said,
>   i don't do windows, but i'll accept a patch that does this.

I have been searching for answer all day please do anybody really know how to do this
or at least point me in the right direction?

**And what is the c compiler for?**

Comment: I think your caps lock key is stuck. Is'n it? (If you don't know already, typing in all caps is like yelling and it's not part of a good netiquette (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netiquette).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I have downloaded and installed MySQL from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) and it solved my problem.